# Is there a DRY way to call different Ruby methods with the same parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code like this.

```
if star
  href = star_path( :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id ))
else
  href = unstar_path( :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id ))
end
```

As you can see, it's calling either the star_path or the unstar_path helper, but with the same parameters. I feel bad repeating the parameters like this, it feels like there should be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: can you not do something like href = star_path( :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id, :star_unstar_boolean_flag => True)

Comment: I'd prefer to keep those methods separate, since they point to different places and do different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
href =
send(
  star ? :star_path : :unstar_path,
  "star[model]".to_sym => model.class, "star[model_id]".to_sym => model.id
)
```

Comment: Send is the most general purpose solution. Thanks

Comment: i wonder why superluminary's answer wasn't selected if we're talking about general purposeness.  his answer is way more readable.

Comment: Because that's my own answer, distilled from the others. It felt rude to choose my own.

Comment: i disagree with that. an answer chosen should be the best even if it's your own.  for me, this is the least readable of all answers which is why i will choose your answer over this.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
options = { :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id }

if star
  href = star_path(options)
else
  href = unstar_path(options)
end
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution, when all you have is an options hash. Thanks.

Comment: This is not as DRY, but I would pick it anytime over anything with `send` in it.

Answer (score 3):

two ways:

- assign to a variable first

  ```
  path_options = :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id
  href = star ? star_path( path_options ) : unstar_path( path_options )
  ```
- use a custom helper

  ```
  def custom_star_path( options = {} )
    action = options.delete( :action ) || :star
    action == :star ? star_path( options ) : unstar_path( options )
  end
  ```

  and call with :

  ```
  custom_star_path( :action => (:unstar unless star), :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id )
  ```

  or even simpler:

  ```
  def custom_star_path( options = {} )
    options.delete( :has_star ) ? star_path( options ) : unstar_path( options )
  end

  custom_star_path( :has_star => star, :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id )
  ```

Answer (score 2):

How about a toggle_star_path helper

```
def toggle_star_path star, model
  options = { :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id }
  star ? unstar_path(options) : star_path(options)
end
```

Then in your view you just call:

```
toggle_star_path star, model
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a variable method, then I think `send` is way to go.

According to the [document](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
 send(symbol [, args...]) → obj
 send(string [, args...]) → obj
```

> Invokes the method identified by symbol/string, passing it any arguments specified. You can use `__send__` if the name send clashes with an existing method in obj. When the method is identified by a string, the string is converted to a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

try as follow, simple 2 lines

```
options = { :"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id }

href = star ? star_path(options) : unstar_path(options)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use ternary operator in this case? like `href = star ? star_path(options) : unstar_path(options)`

Answer (score 0):

Working with the other solutions posted here, I settled on this:

```
options = {:"star[model]" => model.class, :"star[model_id]" => model.id}
href = send((star ? :unstar_path : :star_path ), options)
```